# Deleting question on SO for teams warns of question ban that won't happen

Tags: bug, status-deferred, deleted-questions, stack-overflow-for-teams, warning-message

When deleting a question on SO for Teams:

[image: Delete this answered question? We do not recommend deleting questions with answers because doing so deprives future readers of this knowledge. See "I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?" for alternatives to deletion. Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking. Are you sure you wish to delete?]

The message is wrong: question bans don't exist on Teams.

Comment: I don't use Teams but I wonder if there's any kind of penalty to deleting questions with answers there? In any case, I think the first paragraph is still relevant.

Comment: Don't we all remember that one colleague we would love to get them banned?

Comment: @rene Actually you can suspend people's accounts, by making requests to the right endpoints.  I once lost 100 rep because of a spam or offensive flag in teams that turned out to be testing.

Comment: @Juice I don't mean to be rude but will you post an answer or a comment to elaborate on the retag?